# C# Console.WriteLine not printing in one line

Tags: c#, console

Now if you run this it does not output each `Console.WriteLine` in one line, why?
I know console.writeline goes to next line when done but the problem is it jumps to next line while printing when it print the exception var it is not in the same line as the rest of the writeline
The error occurs inside the `Display()` function at the number 6 variable (exception) it is not in the same line as the rest of the writeline, why?

And also there are no line breaks where the error ocurs.

`Ans` can be any number you like.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
namespace EquationSolver
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string exception = "No Solution Found yet";
        public static int go = 40;
        public static Decimal x = 0, formul = 0;
        public static Decimal pref = -100000, next = 100000,ans;
        public static Decimal stepval = next / 10;
        public static Decimal prefrem = 1234567890123.1234567890m, nextrem = 1234567890123.1234567890m;
        public static Decimal nextremfirst = 0;
        public static void Answer()
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Enter ans");
          ans = (Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine()));

        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Enter ans");
            //Answer(Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine()));
            Answer();
            //Console.Clear();

            while (true)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i <= go; i++)
                {
                    for (x = pref; x <= next; x += stepval)
                    {
                        formul = x;
                        if (formul < ans)
                            prefrem = x;
                        else if (formul > ans)
                        {
                            if (nextremfirst == 0)
                            {
                                nextrem = x;
                                nextremfirst += 2;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (formul == ans)
                        {
                            AnsFound();
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Error();
                        }
                        Display();
                    }

                    if (formul == ans)
                    {
                        AnsFound();
                        break;
                    }
                    if (prefrem != 1234567890123.1234567890m)
                        pref = prefrem;
                    if (nextrem != 1234567890123.1234567890m)
                        next = nextrem;
                    nextremfirst = 0;
                    stepval /= 10;
                    if (formul != ans)
                        NoAnsyet();

                    //Console.WriteLine();
                }
                Finnish();
            }
        }
        public static void Display()
        {
            //Console.ReadKey();
            //Console.WriteLine("Formul: {0} x: {1} Ans: {2} Status: {3}", //formul, x, ans, exception);

//Here is the error:
            Console.WriteLine("Pref:{0} Next:{1} Step:{2} Formul:{3} x:{4} Ans:{5} Status:{6}",pref,next,stepval,formul,x,ans,exception);
        }
        public static void Finnish()
        {
            if (formul != ans)
                Error();
            exception = "\ncomplete";
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
            pref = -100000;
            next =  100000;
            stepval = next /= 10;
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
            //Console.WriteLine("Enter ans:");
            //Answer(Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine()));
            Answer();
        }
        public static void AnsFound()
        {
            exception = "\nSolution Found!";
            //Console.WriteLine("x: {0} Ans: {1} Status: {2}", x, ans, exception);
            //Console.WriteLine("Pref:{0} Next: {1} Stepval: {2}     Formul:{3} x:{4} Ans:{5}  Status:{}", pref, next, stepval, formul, x, ans, exception);

        }
        public static void NoAnsyet()
        {
            exception = "\nNo Solution yet...";
            //Console.WriteLine(exception);
        }
        public static void Error()
        {
            exception = "\nNo Solution error!!";
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine writes the text on a new line. It basically puts a '\n' character before the text. If you need it all on one line, use Console.Write()

Comment: @StevenWood - line terminator is at the end. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.7.2.

Comment: Ohh i see thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you set `exception = "\ncomplete";` at different places. The `\n` at the beginning is a new line character.

Remove the `\n`

```
exception = "complete";
```

Same problem with other texts like `"\nSolution Found!"`.

---

Using string interpolation makes string formatting more readable:

Replace

```
Console.WriteLine("Pref:{0} Next:{1} Step:{2} Formul:{3} x:{4} Ans:{5} Status:{6}",
    pref, next, stepval, formul, x, ans, exception);
```

by

```
Console.WriteLine(
$"Pref:{pref} Next:{next} Step:{stepval} Formul:{formul} x:{x} Ans:{ans} Status:{exception}");
```

Comment: //Here is the error:
            Console.WriteLine("Pref:{0} Next:{1} Step:{2} Formul:{3} x:{4} Ans:{5} Status:{6}",pref,next,stepval,formul,x,ans,exception);  why does it print the exeption var on a new line inside the same writeline?

Comment: Because the exception starts with a new-line character `\n`. You set it like this in different methods: `exception = "\nsome text";` remove the `\n`!

Comment: Thanks helped me a lot :))

Answer (score 0):

Write**Line** writes in a New Line. You should try

`Console.Write()`

If you want to print right after your previous print.

Answer (score 0):

The value to your variable `exception` is the reason why the console is printing on a different basically if you put a special character `\n` means new line hence all the methods you are calling have this special character.

Solution remove special characters and use the `Console.WriteLine` or `Console.Write` methods

Answer (score 0):

As per the code provided you have not called the method i made some changes to the code 
       [Edited code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4PV3.png)
and try to run the code status :No solution found yet
Thanks

Comment: Hi malukas,if we want to get to next line,use console.writeLine or use \n(just like in c) so1)console.writeline("your code") 2)console.write("\n yourcode") .....